# Looking for a term for acting on incorrect information

Tags: bias, cognitive

I'm looking for a term to describe one of my favorite aphorisms:  "It's not what you don't know that gets you into trouble, it's what you think you know that's wrong."

Is there a term for this in the dictionary of cognitive biases?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: See [mind projection fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_projection_fallacy), [psychic equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychic_equivalence), and [availability heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Availability_heuristic).